# Collision detection in Java ufo game

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision, stanford-nlp

I have a simple Java game where you fire a bullet up at a moving target. Both objects are GRects. I have collision detection that checks when the ufo and bullet intersect each other, but here is the weirdness:

This works:

```
private void collideWithUFO() { 
    if (bullet != null) {
        GObject collObj = getElementAt(ufo.getX(), ufo.getY()); 
        if (collObj == bullet) {
            remove(ufo); 
            remove(bullet); 
            ufo = null; 
            bullet = null;
        }
     }
}
```

..but if I change the `getElementAt` to bullet like below, and check with respect to ufo, it fails to detect collisions:

```
private void collideWithUFO() { 
    if (bullet != null) {
        GObject collObj = getElementAt(bullet.getX(), bullet.getY()); 
        if (collObj == ufo) {
            remove(ufo); 
            remove(bullet); 
            ufo = null; 
            bullet = null;
        }
     }
 }
```

It should be irrelevant whether I choose ufo or bullet first, but apparently it isn't. Now here is something that's even WEIRDER. If I change the bullet from GRect to GOval, all of a sudden the second form of collision detection works. I am a Java noob so please let me know if this behavior makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public GObject getElementAt(double x, double y)

Returns the topmost graphical object that contains the point (x, y), or null if no such object exists.
```

So `getElementAt(bullet.getX(), bullet.getY())` will only give you the ufo if the ufo is the topmost graphical element, otherwise you will get the bullet.

Comment: Thanks, now I see. This must also mean that changing the bullet from GRect to GOval puts it below the UFO object, too.